# MAMP PRO document root forbidden when adding ssl

Tags: apache, ssl, mamp-pro

Just upgraded to Mamp Pro 3.5 from simple MAMP and all worked great till I added a self signed cert.

My document root for my local.mysite.com was set to htdocs/html/magento

Site works fine using http.
When I add the self signed ssl the site now only works correctly at https pages. If I try to go to any page without https such as http://local.mysite.com/store I get this in the apache log:

File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/store

If I uncheck the ssl the http urls all work again.
Did I miss something in the set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far from obvious, but you can actually add a second host with the exact same domain name (local.mysite.com in your case) but this time leave SSL disabled on the SSL tab.

You'll therefore have two hosts, both for local.mysite.com. One is for https and the other for http.

Comment: This is true. Thanks